# Hotlinks in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've been developing graphics in a graphics editor and I was able to add hot links to navigate through to different graphics, by entering the pathway to the graphic file. However there is now a new version of editor makes you publish the graphics online and view them from the web and the hotlink option is replaced with a button option. Instead of being able to enter the pathway of the graphic file I want to link to I have to enter a JavaScript script, that will run on click, and I have no clue how to get the JavaScript to work like the hotlink was working.

I have looked up tutorials on JavaScript but cant get any of the code to work on my button even simple things like alerts and prompts. If anyone has any idea how to these buttons work or if its possible for them to behave like the hotlinks from before that would be great.

Comment: Please insert the code you have tried. Both HTML and JavaScript. It is very difficult to help without that.

Comment: This sounds a little like you want to use a [`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) element to create an image map?

Answer (score 0):

Well it largely depends on your software, which you didn't mention here. However, if in the end it will be displayed in browser, you can try something like this:

For link, use `javascript: alert('test');` and see if that gives you an alert box when you click it. If it does, problem solved.

If not, I am affraid you'll have to provide more information about your software before someone can offer some advice.